# How to write webservice response to a json file?

Tags: java, json

I am getting the response from webservice request which I am able to print on the console. I want to write this response to a json file. I tried with buffereWriter but it did not write.

```
String cwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
buffereWriter writer = new buffereWriter (new File writer(cwd + "filepath"));
Writer.write(response);

// This response is being currently displayed in the console correctly.
```

There are no error or exception but the content is not getting written in the file.

Comment: what is `response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FileWriter` for that. Also a `try block` with resources which will guarantee your file will be closed.

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(cwd + "filepath")){

    fw.write(response); //I guess the response is a String.

}catch(Exception ignored){}
```